# Ignorar etiqueta

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Cuando decido ignorar una etiqueta, ¿Debería mostrarme aún las preguntas con las etiquetas que decidí ignorar?

Por ejemplo:

Ignoro la etiqueta [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), aún me siguen apareciendo pero no tan enfocadas como las otras, con un color gris. Aunque tenga otras etiquetas incluidas en la pregunta.

Answer (score 12):

Eso ya está informado en su sección.

> Las Etiquetas Ignoradas obscurecen los temas en los que no estas interesado. Preguntas con esas etiquetas se ven semi-transparentes en la página principal y en las listas de preguntas, pero siguen visibles. **Si quieres, puedes ocultarlas completamente marcando el cuadro "Ocultar las preguntas con mis etiquetas ignoradas " en la ficha "Preferencias" de la sección "Edición de perfil y configuración" de tu perfil de usuario.**

Fuente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics

---

Acá un ejemplo visual de como hacerlo desde la p{agina inicial además. Otro usuario dijo que no podía encontrar la opción en preferencias, pero se puede desde el mismo inicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta configuración ha cambiado? No la encuentro...

Comment: La manera más simple incluso es desde la página principal, sección de etiquetas ignoradas. Agregare esa imagen.

Comment: @OCHOA espero ese modo sea mas simple

Comment: Ahora si, pero la opción de **Preferencias** no se ve. Justo por eso no pude hacerlo. Ahora creo que desde la página principal se hace. Gracias.